# Spring MockMVC Test weird behaviour. single vs "all" execution

Tags: spring, spring-security, mockmvc

I am currently experiencing a weird issue regarding Spring's MockMvc in combination with Spring Security in JUnit Tests.

When I run a whole class of tests, everything works fine and the tests are passing.
But when I run All Tests in the Project one test is always failing in that certain class and it doesn't matter if I remove the test method failing, then another one fails in the same class.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith({RestDocumentationExtension.class, SpringExtension.class})
class AuthenticationApiTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(RestDocumentationContextProvider documentation) {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(documentation)
                        .operationPreprocessors()
                        .withRequestDefaults(prettyPrint(),removeHeaders("Content-Length","Host","Pragma","X-XSS-Protection","Expires","X-Frame-Options","X-Content-Type-Options","Cache-Control"))
                        .withResponseDefaults(prettyPrint(),removeHeaders("Content-Length","Host","Pragma","X-XSS-Protection","Expires","X-Frame-Options","X-Content-Type-Options","Cache-Control")))
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }
```

The test which fails:

```
@Test
    public void testSignUpFail() throws Exception {
        SignUpBody signUpBody = new SignUpBody();
        signUpBody.setPassword("demo1234");
        signUpBody.setFirstname("first");
        signUpBody.setLastname("lastn");

        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/auth/user/signup")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(signUpBody))
        ).andExpect(status().is(400))
                .andDo(document("user-signup-fail"));

        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/auth/vendor/signup")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(signUpBody))
        ).andExpect(status().is(400))
                .andDo(document("vendor-signup-fail"));
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this weird issue?

Comment: I've hit a similar issue recently, it was due to some `static` caching down the rabbit hole that wasn't reset properly between tests (or something along those lines). Perhaps this can help.

Comment: Ah, this was it for the record: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/issues/1784.